# SQL insert statement - missing select keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very very new to SQL language, and trying to execute the following code. It gives me an error message below.. What did I do wrong?

Error Message:

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
```

Code:

```
WITH ABC(one,two,three)
AS(
  select 25, 15,23 from dual
  )
INSERT INTO ABC(one, two, three) VALUES (10,11,12)
select * from ABC;
```

Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT** -- Explanation
I need to create table with more than 100 rows. I am not allowed to create new table due to sufficient privilege, so I am trying to create virtual table. The idea on my head is inserting rows to the virtual table with For-loop. But this 'missing select keyword' error occurs when I try to insert any record...

**EDIT** -- Regarding the word "very very new to SQL language"
I am currently a computer engineering student in University, and studied 'Database' course last year. Now, I am doing an internship. So like.. I am not like a beginner who needs w3school tutorial, but I am new to 'SQL language for real life'

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: semicolon at the end of insert line?

Comment: Very new with SQL and starting with common table expressions? Sheesh good luck man! :P

Comment: You cannot insert into a CTE

Comment: @Siyual Question is now updated

Comment: @Steve (Maybe I am wrong) I tried to put semicolon at the end of insert line, but it gave me "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist". I assume that it terminated at the insert statement..

Comment: Same as what Kritner said, I don't think CTE's are a good place to start if your a beginniner. I would go check out w3schools.com sql section

Comment: @Kritner I took "database course" in school, but the real life is killing me... :(

Comment: @Adrian Ah, I see, as @Donal stated, you cannot insert into a CTE, which is what you're creating with the `With` statement.  You'll want to create a table variable instead if you can't create a physical table.  Or if you have the ability to create a temporary table, that can work as well.

Comment: As an FYI, many Oracle database installation have the scott/tiger user account.  Perhaps you can login to that and perform your prototyping with standard tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another "table" that returns the number of rows you want. In Oracle this is usually done using an undocumented feature of the `connect by` operator:

```
select level as rn 
from dual
connect by level <= 100
```

The "undocumented" part is the fact that no real "connect" is done and no `start with` is supplied. Look up the `connect by` in the manual for more details on this.

will return 100 rows. You can combine this with your initial CTE and do a cross join to return the single row a hundred times:

```
WITH abc (one,two,three) AS (
  select 25, 15,23 from dual
), num_rows as (
  select level as rn 
  from dual
  connect by level <= 100
) 
select abc.* 
from abc
  cross join num_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with `union all` like this:

```
WITH ABC(one,two,three)
AS(
  select 25, 15,23 from dual union all
  select 10,11,12 from dual
  )
select * from ABC
```

Comment: tedious right? But if you fill your table inserting values one by one i think this is the only way to do this. The other way is filling it through a query, but i think this is not your case

Comment: It's not tedious if you use Excel to generate the expressions. Where do your 100 data values come from anyway? Are they random values or are they sitting in an Excel sheet somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a table

```
SELECT (21)as a,(22)as b,(23)as c
INTO #Test
SELECT * FROM #Test
```

This will create a table as well.

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TestTable
FROM dual
```

Assuming that dual is a valid table in your database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the question is edited. "I need to create (virtual) table with more than 100 rows"

Comment: @Adrian I think you mean temporary table, which should lead you on your Google quest.

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle.